# Python Authomatic with local user/pass database?

Tags: python, authentication, wsgi

I'm considering bringing authentication into my project (I currently use Auth0) and came across Authomatic which looks cool and promising.

A little background: I have a bare (no framework) WSGI app and I'd like to support both database logins and social logins.  I see Authomatic has good support for social/OAuth(2) providers, so I'm guessing it has everything I need (presumably generating secure cookies/tokens to authenticate the session) except a local provider.

So the parts I would need to add would be:
 1. a WSGI adapter
 2. a local/database provider e.g., like https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/tree/master/examples/express3-mongoose

I'm guessing it's not too hard to add a local/database provider but I wanted to check: 1. Is this is a good idea, am I thinking about it correctly?  and 2. Has anyone done this already?

Many thanks!